# Managing values of data within a WPF Combo Box items

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I have a WPF combo box where the user have to pick between a paper size.
For example cmb_papersize has a collection of sub-items of paper sizes:

> A3 - 297x420 mm
>
> F4 - 215x330 mm
>
> etc...

This combo box input will be linked to a method to determine the paper size.

Typically I would use a Select...Case where I compare the combo box item index and set the variables:

```
Private Sub SetPaperSize()
    Select Case cmb_papersize.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
           PageWidth = 297
           PageHeight = 420
        Case 1
           PageWidth = 215
           PageHeight = 330
       'etc....
    End Select
End Sub
```

However I'm curious if there are more elegant way to do this? Managing two variables maybe is simple enough with Select...Case, however I'm planning to add more variables like measurement units, margins, etc.. especially if I want to add more paper size and each sizes will definitely have different values.

I'm thinking to use properties or using arrays, putting the data in different class, etc... but I can't think how should I do it.

Comment: You can bind the control to a list of items that have (at least) two properties.  You set the `DisplayMemberPath` to the name of the property you want displayed in the control and the `SelectedValuePath` to the name of the property you want exposed via the `SelectedValue`.  If the latter property is something with width and height components, you can get the selected dimensions from the `SelectedValue` of the control, get the width and height components and assign them directly without the need for any `If` of `Select Case`. You could use a `System.Windows.Size` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment above:

> You can bind the control to a list of items that have (at least) two
>   properties.  You set the `DisplayMemberPath` to the name of the
>   property you want displayed in the control and the `SelectedValuePath`
>   to the name of the property you want exposed via the `SelectedValue`. 
>   If the latter property is something with width and height components,
>   you can get the selected dimensions from the `SelectedValue` of the
>   control, get the width and height components and assign them directly
>   without the need for any `If` of `Select Case`. You could use a
>   `System.Windows.Size` value.

Here is a simple example:

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        Dim items As New List(Of PaperSize) From {New PaperSize With {.Name = "A3", .Dimensions = New Size(297, 420)},
                                                  New PaperSize With {.Name = "F4", .Dimensions = New Size(215, 330)}}

        With cmb_papersize
            .SelectedValuePath = "Dimensions"
            .ItemsSource = items
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim dimensions = DirectCast(cmb_papersize.SelectedValue, Size)
        Dim pageWidth = dimensions.Width
        Dim pageHeight = dimensions.Height

        MessageBox.Show($"Page dimensions: {pageWidth} by {pageHeight}")
    End Sub
End Class


Friend Class PaperSize

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Dimensions As Size

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{Name} - {Dimensions.Width}x{Dimensions.Height} mm"
    End Function

End Class
```

Note that, because I haven't set the `DisplayMemberPath`, the control displays the result of calling `ToString` on each item, which is the reason for overriding `ToString` in the `PaperSize` class.